# two diffrent datset to show values as subdata in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have a problem i am creating a crystal report which have two dataset one of product and another one of quantity i want show it both but quantity below/diffrent column but match the product in the crystal report can it be done.

example

```
dataset1        dataset2
product price   quantity    person
     a  10        5          abc
     b  20        2          xyz
     c  15        9          lmn
```

but this is not what i am getting the unmatched result my both dataset is not merged
they show unmatched result like if quantity is missing of b then c's data is shown in b's data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the expirence that i h ave with cristal report,i can suggest to make just one dataset, that contains all the data you need to display, so crystal just need to render your data.
If you can't change this maybe you can resolve that just grouping your data by "product" and moving in the header of the group the others field you need!!!

I hope it can help you!!!

Answer (score 1):

use this link for reference

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/subreports-in-crystal-reports-in-aspnet.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Crystal_Reports_in_net.aspx